# Copy all files and folders from one folder Batch

Tags: batch-file

How do I copy every file and folder from one folder to another directory?

copy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\" "C:\Newfolder\"

How do I make a shortcut of all files and folders from one folder to another directory?

copy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\" "C:\Newfolder*.ink"

Comment: The `%username%` folder contains system files that Xcopy will not copy, so `every file` is not possible without using `volume shadow copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XCopy SoucrceFolder TargetFolder /s /E
```

this will copy all the files , folder structure (even the empty once)

not sure if you would be able to create .lnks with batch file but through windows
you can do as shown below. OR. drag drop files with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> pressed it will create links

[image]

Comment: what if i would love to move all files and folders from a folder to another?

Comment: can you be precise? IMO, you should consider posting fresh question.

Comment: just like we did with xcopy just with move;
move "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\" "C:\"
Just without delete Desktop + cd ...%username% + mkdir Desktop

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is follow the following sample and it should work.

```
xcopy sourcefolder destinationfolder
```

To copy a folder and it's subfolders/files use this.

```
xcopy c:\folder\*.* d:\another_folder\.
```

For your second question i don't know, sorry.

Comment: I actually didn't know that, what is the difference between the S and the E in terms of what they do?

Comment: here is direct from ms dos help

/S           Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
/E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.

Comment: That's what I'd expect, but I get `File not found - *.*`