# In batch, how would I copy every file in a folder to another file

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to copy every file from one folder to another but I can't get it to work. Whats wrong with this code?

```
@echo off
cd desktop
cd bukkit plugins/player_pacman/src
for /r %%f in (*) do (
    copy %%f %f:bukkit plugins=github%
    echo Coppied %%f
)
echo Done copying files
pause
```

Comment: Have you tried using `XCOPY`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122932/copy-all-files-and-folders-from-one-folder-batch

Comment: I put in an answer.  If you would, please uprate and accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `XCOPY`.  It can search entire directory trees for subsets of files.